# Using Globalized Redux Selector In Side Effect Creates Circular Dependency

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

I'm storing form data in redux store after normalizing it using `normalizr`. When I submit the form, I get the denormalized data using selectors inside my thunk and then send it to the server. The flow goes the following way:

`rootReducer -> localReducer -> action/actionCreator -> rootReducer`

In `rootReducer` file, the root reducer composes `localReducer` and contains the globalized selector to be used later in the thunk. The `localReducer` file imports actions from the actions file which contains the action creators too. The thunk action creator returns a thunk which does the api call using data retrieved by the selector in `rootReducer` file, hence the circular dependency.

Webpack is not handling well this circular dependency. I got a runtime `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'JOB_FORM_RESET' of undefined` error at the `localReducer -> action/actionCreator` level:

```
const jobsForm = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.JOB_FORM_RESET:
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

### Edit

`ActionTypes` being evaluated to `undefined` works as specced. `ActionTypes` is located in the `action/actionCreator` file whose execution didn't finish when it was first imported by `localReducer` because it started immediately importing the `rootReducer`. In order to avoid the infinite loop, an unfinished copy of `action/actionCreator` (where `ActionTypes` is evaluated to `undefined`) is given to `localReducer`.

The solution is to separate the actions and action creators by putting them in two different files. This will remove the cyclic dependency as shown in the following flow:

```
rootReducer -> localReducer -> action
actionCreator -> rootReducer
```

The weird thing for me is that grouping action and action creators has been advocated in redux guidelines since too long and separating them in two files feels less natural.

In addition, this cyclic issue doesn't appear in `redux-saga` model:

```
rootReducer -> localReducer -> action/actionCreator
saga -> api -> rootReducer
```

I'm used to this model but can't believe that `redux-thunk` model doesn't solve this issue. In other words, it doesn't seem fair to say that the cyclic issue is an inherent side effect of the `redux-thunk` model. Am I missing something here?

You can find an MCVE in this [repo](https://github.com/ahmehri/redux-thunk-globalized-selectors-cyclic-dependencies). The error is different but it's the same principle, it was caused by a cyclic dependencies caused by the following import in `src/Users/actions.js` file:
`import { getSelectedUsers } from '../reducer';`

The occurred error is `No reducer provided for key "users"`. Just comment the above import and the error will disappear.

As I describe above, this works as specced, my concern is that the `redux-thunk` model doesn't handle this use case. In addition, putting actions and action creators both in the same file and then wait for a cyclic dependencies issue to occur to separate them doesn't seem a scalable solution.

Comment: split the selector to a separate file so that the thunk can import that instead of `rootReducer`?

Comment: I'm following a very well known redux guideline where the globalized selectors are the ones who are imported and used (localized selectors are used in chains). In theory this should work and I want to keep using it as it is without trying workarounds.

Comment: could you provide a minimum verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve instead of writing about how your code operates? It'd save tons of cognitive cycles for readers and would  increase the speed and quality of response.

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is quite simple: Extract actionTypes to separate file and import it in `actions.js` and `reducer.js`

`actionTypes.js` file:

`export const SELECT_USER = 'SELECT_USER';
export const POST_USERS = 'POST_USERS';`

You can import all actions at once like this

`import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes.js'`

Problem solved here:

https://github.com/svitekpavel/redux-thunk-globalized-selectors-cyclic-dependencies/commit/1c7f04fc5c1d4e4155891428138f8cb00412655e

Two more recommendations:

1. Extract selectors to separate file
2. Extract "effects" (`postUsers`) to effects.js

The second recommendation comes from experience, that these functions (side effects) that tutorials of `redux-thunks` keep in `actions.js` are actually side effects and not action creators.

If you were to use Redux-Saga, you would quickly realize that decoupling business logic (and side effects) from action creators is a good thing.

Also, they are two separate things :-)

Comment: I already mentioned the solution you described in my question post, and also mentioned that the problem doesn't exist when using redux-saga. My concern here is how to avoid this problem when using redux-thunk. More details are in the question post.

Comment: `to separate them doesn't seem a scalable solution`
=> what exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: Separating action types and action creators from the beginning is easy. This is not the case when they were put in the same file from the beginning, the code has been evolved a lot, and then we decide to separate them. It will need a lot of refactoring especially if there are a lot of existing references.